# Finding a function whose composite with another given return the identity function

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I am asked to answer the following:

Let $f:Z->Z$ be defined by $f(x) = 2x$.

- Write down infinitely many functions $g:Z->Z$ such that $g(f(x)) = Id_z$

I thought that the right reasoning was simply to find the inverse of $f$, since it is that function such that $f(g(x)) = Id_z$.
Hence, $g(x) = $$x\over 2$.

However, I'm asked infinitely many functions which made me think of the introduction of a parameter $k$. And here is exactly where I am stuck.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the functions $$g_k(x) = \begin{cases} \frac x2 & \text{if $x$ is even}\\ k &\text{otherwise}?\end{cases}$$

Notice that $f$ only outputs even numbers, so when composed with $g$, it doesn't matter what the outputs for odd values are.

In other words for any $k$, observe that $$(g_k\circ f)(x) = g(2x) = \frac{2x}{2} = x$$ since $2x$ is even.

Comment: Oh, I see. This makes much more sense now. 

I really didn't think of a piece-wise function, but it actually does answer the question and explains why there infinitely many inverses. 

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the composition to be identity you only need $g(x)=\frac x 2$ when  $x$ is even. No condition is needed for $x$ odd. Can you now think of infinitely many functions $g$ such that $g\circ f=id$?
Example: $g(1)=k, g(x)=0$ for $k$ odd and $\neq 1$, $g(x)=\frac x 2$ for $x$ even. This satisfies the requirements for every $k$.

Comment: I am not really sure that I have understood. Could you say the final part again?

Thanks

Comment: The condition $g (f(2x))=x$ involves only values of $g$ at even integers  because $2x$ is always even.  So, whatever value you take for $g(x)$ when $x$ is odd you will have $g (f(x))=x$ provided $g(x)=\frac x 2$ for $x$ even. I  chose arbitrary values for $g(1)$ to get infinitely many functions $g$. @Fede1